# cvResize Explanation, OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have already studied Computer Vision for a while and read OpenCV source code. It's frustrating because the source code does not seem clear to me. I had a particular issue with cvResize. I understand linear interpolation, but the code is too complex to read. Is there anybody who knows how cvResize works and the structure is setup up who can explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very recommended to look at OpenCV's source code, mainly because of these reasons:

1. If you're using the C interface, you're probably looking at a wrapper of the C++ interface (which is the one you should use if you're using OpenCV >= 2.0).
2. Many abstractions exist to work on all image types (precision, number of channels etc).
3. Hardware-specific optimizations makes the code even more complex (such as SSE/AVX optimizations for x86/x64).
4. Specifically in the resize method, there could be many edge cases to handle considering the source/target image size.

To understand in a high-level how the code works, I strongly suggest to read about [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation), [nearest neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) and [Lanczos resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling), and look for resizing implementations in a scientific-oriented language such as Matlab. Knowledge in signal processing and/or linear systems will help you understand the differences in quality of these filters.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV documentation is blurred and if you are going through the source code, I assume you are pretty much angry at the source code, just like me :) Well it takes a while, lots of experimentation and read on-line. Slowly you fill the gaps

1. Assuming you are using C interface of OpenCV
2. You probably should go through[this book](http://books.google.com.pk/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=opencv%20cvresize&source=bl&ots=hSK27jeJSc&sig=ipJRwU72ckqgU2CNRY1THSS3q2w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D8jKUePoNYa0PL7vgdgN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=opencv%20cvresize&f=false) for learning about cvResize
3. You are not going to learn all the options for cvResize unless you
   understand what interpolation, bilinear, cubic means. These are not hard stuff but you      must know at little theory and then test the code by writing programs yourself.